# Excel approximate matches in two columns?

Tags: excel, data-manipulation

I am comparing two columns with names, but the name of the columns not always uniformly in two columns(column 1 = 3M Inc and column 2 = 3M incorporate ). i used Vlookup TRUE condition but its showing several error. i am working on 50000 line items.

Vlookup with TRUE condition.
Match

Comment: Look into [`Fuzzy Lookup Addin`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please post a data example of what are you trying to get? the input and the expected output.

Comment: Thanks its worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Wildcard (**"*"**) match in the VLOOKUP formula and with FALSE condition. See the attached screenshot below.

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&E2&"*",$A$2:$B$7,1,FALSE)
```

Please checkout the Column F in the below image which looks for data in the respective
cell from Column E from the Main Data.

[image: VLOOKUP Wild card]

**Resources:** You can check out the following video from Leila to see how the WildCard works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9WoDkPOTPs